# JavaFX media issue on Ubuntu : Could not create player

Tags: java, javafx, ffmpeg, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to play mp3 file on JavaFX-11.0.2 on Ubuntu-20.04 using JDK-13.0.2 but I keep getting this same error every time. While I was searching for that I found that JavaFX uses older version of some libraries([See this issue on github](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/331)). So I compiled and installed ffmpeg-3.1.11 from source. But the same exception is thrown. I put my code and error message bellow. I stuck on this for days so I really appreciate any help. Thanks.

note : This is not duplicate qeustion. All other questions regarding to this error happend on different versions and had different causes. I tried most of them but none of them works for me.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-13.0.2/bin/java --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media -Djava.library.path=/opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib -javaagent:/opt/idea-IU-201.7846.76/lib/idea_rt.jar=46237:/opt/idea-IU-201.7846.76/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/parsa/Documents/welanner/target/classes:/opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/src.zip:/opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx-swt.jar:/opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.web.jar:/opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.base.jar:/opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.fxml.jar:/opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.media.jar:/opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.swing.jar:/opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.controls.jar:/opt/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar:/home/parsa/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.jar view.GUI
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:518)
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:421)
    at view.GUI.start(GUI.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.media/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:295)
    at javafx.media/com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:474)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application view.GUI

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my code. I know path and other things are correct because I can run it on Windows properly.

```
package view;

import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

public class GUI extends javafx.application.Application{
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        String path = "/home/parsa/Music/Ninoush.mp3";
        Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        stage.setTitle("Playing audio");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my ffmpeg and libraries versions :

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.11 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
configuration: 
libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
```

Edit 3 : I can play wav file this way but I can't play mp3.

Comment: the resources lookup is wrong (see the faq on how to do it correctly), not closing as duplicate because there might be another problem. and don't post images of text ..

Comment: @kleopatra can you hlep me more about resources lookup? were should i look for that?

Comment: as I said: see the faq (in the javafx tag wiki .. click the learn-more link near the top of the page showing the list of questions for javafx)

Comment: @kleopatra I don't think that is the problem because this code run on windows properly.

Comment: if it's working, that's accidentally - for building correct and robust software, you must stick to the specification (which states exactly which format the resource lookup it expects), always, no exception ..

Comment: @kleopatra You are right. I change the code(also in question) but I still getting that same error.

Comment: I also get the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @TharinduSathischandra This is not solved yet. I used another file format to implement my program.

Comment: @parsa2820 which format did u used?

Comment: @TharinduSathischandra I used wav. You can easily convert mp3 to wav using ffmpeg.

Comment: just wonder have you solved this problem yet? I had the same problem,: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66939226/8487819, and I also met another strange problem with playing audio file in loop mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to update javafx, javafx 16 can play mp3 file successfully on ubuntu 20.
you can download it from here: [javafx download link](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for a very long time. In fact, it didn't work for me on any Linux distro. Try running it on Windows or Mac. But you can look for a solution (Which I didn't get after looking for a week).

Comment: I didn't come along with any solution yet. It seems there is few JavaFX developer using Gnu/Linux out there :D. I think JavaFX media isn't able to locate and use mp3 related codec. Didn't you found similar thing like this?

Comment: Yes I did. They said it was fixed in Java 8 but didn't work anyway. Just quit it its a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with JDK 17, many other thread suggest installing **libav-tools**, but it seems like it has been deprecated and is no longer available in recent versions of Ubuntu.

Therefore you can install **ffmpeg** instead. After installing this, it worked fine for me.

`sudo apt install ffmpeg`