# Javafx can't play mp3 file with MediaException on ubuntu 20

Tags: java, javafx, gstreamer

1. configuration: ubuntu 20, javafx 11, jdk15, language level 8
2. problem: mp3 file could be directly play on ubuntu, while can't be played in following code, but the code can be used to play *.wav and *.aiff audio files, except mp3:

```
    Media media = new Media(new File("assets/audios/shoot.mp3").toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.play();
```

3. exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:518)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:421)
    at com.aldora.tankwar.Tools.playSound(Tools.java:18)
    at com.aldora.tankwar.App.main(App.java:146)
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:295)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:474)
```

4. debug result: `com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTPlatform.createMediaPlayer` throws media error: ERROR_MEDIA_NULL

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found this can't be walked around by upgrading javafx, switching from javafx11 to javafx16 can solve it.
[javafx download link](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in java's "sound.properties" config file. I'm now on Ubuntu 20.04, with java-11-openjdk, so, edited `/etc/java-11-openjdk/sound.properties` and added the following lines at the end:

```
javax.sound.sampled.Clip=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider
javax.sound.sampled.Port=com.sun.media.sound.PortMixerProvider
javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider
javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine=com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDeviceProvider
```

For deep in, read: https://keithp.com/blogs/Java-Sound-on-Linux/